# Citation `kordic2008analysis' on page 1 undefined in TeXstudio

Tags: bibliographies

when I run the `tex` file in `TeXstudio`, it shows:

> Citation `kordic2008analysis` on page 1 undefined

Below is the entry in the bib file:

```
@inproceedings{kordic2008analysis,

  title={Analysis of alarm sequences in a chemical plant},

  author={Kordic, Savo and Lam, Peng and Xiao, Jitian and Li, Huaizhong},

  booktitle={International Conference on Advanced Data Mining and Applications},

  pages={135-146},

  year={2008},

  organization={Springer}

}
```

I have also changed the build in the configure tex maker option which is:

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex
```

still i am getting the error. I will appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: are you using biblatex?

Comment: Please show us code so we can see what your document looks like. Does your document compile overwise (what you show is technically a _warning_ not an error)